Attach table top to air filter
Might be a strange idea, but we only use our Sqair air purifier in the winter (when the air quality is really bad) and thought it would be a good idea to convert it to a coffee table during the non-winter months. (This would also prevent a lot of dust from getting inside.)

We were thinking through a bunch of table top ideas, from glass to wood to cardboard. I think for aesthetic purposes, wood might be the best option. However, still open to other materials.
The top looks like this, so wondering if any rubber inserts might work.

Looking for ideas on how to make a removable, but stable, table top for this air filter, specifically on how to attach said table top to the filter. Also, if you think this is a bad idea feel free to let me know.

The unit looks to be maybe 10"x10 " or so.   A top of any kind could simply be place on top However it can overhang only 3 inches or so.  That's a pretty small table.

@RMDman the filter is also pretty short—only a little over 13" tall—so IDK if trying to turn it into a coffee table is very practical.  IMO it'd be better to just stash it under an existing coffee table!

Thanks for the feedback! Yes, its a bit on the short side and not very big. I think coffee table was not the right term, I think I meant something closer to a sofa end table. I've put a flat surface on there and have used it for drinks so far, but it seems like a very make shift solution, so the reasoning is if I am currently using it for that purpose, I wonder if I can make it a bit nicer.

It's not a good idea because whatever things you decide should be kept on it in summer, will then have no home for the winter.   I mean, you could put your swim suits on it or something, and then in the summer put them in storage so you can use the filter?   But more seriously I don't see a place in the home for something like a coffee table or a night stand that can only be used half the time.
Technically, it's not a good idea because it's very small so anything you construct to mount it to the top of the filter will be no easier and no more effective than constructing something to rest on the floor, around/over the filter.   In which case you don't need to construct anything you can just buy a "table" and put the filter under it, and use it all year.  In fact, you could just reverse the arrangement in your photo and you're done.

Thanks for the feedback. That is a stock photo, so I don't have a night stand / coffee table already. But still valuable feedback.

If you mounted the device firmly to a sturdy plate, and attached to that plate longer legs that splayed out to offer wider, more stable, support, you could then add a top, no wider than the legs at bottom, to cover the vent.
One could trace the outline of the air cleaner's top on a piece of wood, and use a router (or chisel, for those who prefer), to remove the wood to a few centimeter's depth. Since the device tapers a bit, it could make a nice press-fit in the recess, stable enough to support a box of facial tissues or a book or two, yet easily removable.

I like the press-fit idea... how hard is it to get it to be a perfect / near-perfect fit? Any links to woodworking articles would be helpful on this one.

There is a woodworking stack. It sounds like this question belongs there, rather than here in home improvement.
